# An Odd Poem Found on the Ground

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

I found an odd poem lying around. Who wrote it? When? What is the secret in it?

```
NONE  TO  DO 
ANDNONEAROUND
A zer0.WHERE
 YOU GAZE,REA
LIZE. NOTHING
SAME # zer0ES
AND3NONEleft.
3W    h     X
```

This is my first puzzle on this site, so I'm open to suggestions.

**Hint 1:**

> A change in perspective might be helpful.

**Hint 2:**

> This puzzle could be described as RW^OL⊃+HOZe¬Y

**Hint 3:**

> There's a suspicious amount of Z's...

**Hint 4:**

> There could be something in that last line...

Comment: Can you confirm that the puzzle looks exactly as you intended it?  There's something odd to me.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This seems like a very interesting puzzle - thank you for using the proper tags! (Also, if you're gonna be around here more (which I hope you are!), I'd recommend changing your username to something more memorable.)

Comment: @LeppyR64, everything is correctly typed.

Comment: Some other "perspectives" may be hexadecimal or binary.

Comment: @noneuclideanisms Can we have a new hint ?

Comment: Any chance of a new hint to move this forward?

Comment: Could there be another hint? :0

Answer (score 10):

**Not a complete solution...**

Just to add to [karobar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33327)'s work:

> You can spot the word `NONE` repeated around in a circle:
>  [image]

Given that the words in the original note describe "NONE AROUND A Zer0", we are possibly meant to interpret:

> the circle created by the NONEs as a big `0`, in which case the diagonal through the centre, `E.G.`, may be of importance... (the initials of the author?)

Comment: E.G. is Latin for "for example".

Answer (score 9):

I was really hoping to have all the points for this but I think I'm at a point where I'm stumped. Here's some hints for everybody.

#### Spoiler for hint "This puzzle could be described as RW^OL⊃+HOZe¬Y"

> *This puzzle could be described as REVOLUTIONARY*
>  
>  **Explanation**
>  You can rotate each character in RW^OL⊃+HOZe¬Y to get the word REVOLUTIONARY
>  'W' turned on its side is an 'E'
>  '^' upside-down is a 'V'
>  '⊃' turned right is a 'U'
>  '+' is kinda a 'T'
>  'H' on its side is an 'I'
>  'Z' is a rotated 'N'
>  'e' is a rotated 'a'
>  '¬' is a turned 'r'

#### My analysis of hint #2

> I'm guessing that the poem itself needs to be rotated, so I've rotated around the center point of the 'X'
>  [image]
>  You can see here that the upside down 'h' might be a 4? '3W' seems to be a pretty clear 'ME'
>
>  I also think that the location of the zeroes and periods are very important here, so I've drawn lines between the "outer" zeroes, and each line seems to pass through two periods, which might be important:
>  [image]

And of course I've tried all sorts of other avenues for solutions, fruitlessly. Great puzzle, noneuclideanisms!

Comment: To help you out here: If you track the rotations for the hint, you'll notice that it is rotating 90degrees clockwise each time (0, 90, 180, 270, 360/0, 90...etc). You gave an amazing input!

Comment: Oh snap! By revolutionary we are talking about revolutions (mathematics) vs. history. Or maybe both :D

Answer (score 5):

## Puzzle Information

This is not a solution, but may be helpful in someone else's solution.

Several possible permutations to `a change in perspective` are:
(Spacing was kept)

**Upside Down**

```
3W    h     X
AND3NONEleft.
SAME # zer0ES
LIZE. NOTHING
 YOU GAZE,REA
A zer0.WHERE 
ANDNONEAROUND
NONE  TO  DO
```

**Upside Down, Reversed**

```
X     h    W3  
.tfelENON3DNA  
SE0rez # EMAS  
GNIHTON .EZIL  
AER,EZAG UOY   
 EREHW.0rez A  
DNUORAENONDNA  
 OD  OT  ENON
```

**Reverse**

```
 OD  OT  ENON  
DNUORAENONDNA  
 EREHW.0rez A  
AER,EZAG UOY   
GNIHTON .EZIL  
SE0rez # EMAS  
.tfelENON3DNA  
X     h    W3
```

**90º Clockwise, Reversed**

```
NAA LSA3  
ON YIANW  
NDzOZMD   
ENeUEE3   
 Or . N   
 N0G #O   
TE.AN Nh  
OAWZOzE   
 RHETel   
 OE,Hre   
DURRI0f   
ONEENEt   
 D AGS.X
```

**90º Clockwise**

```
3ASL AAN  
WNAIY NO  
 DMZOzDN  
 3EEUeNE  
 N . rO   
 O# G0N   
hN NA.ET  
 EzOZWAO  
 leTEHR   
 erH,EO   
 f0IRRUD  
 tENEENO  
X.SGA D
```

**90º Counterclockwise**

```
 D AGS.X  
ONEENEt   
DURRI0f   
 OE,Hre   
 RHETel   
OAWZOzE   
TE.AN Nh  
 N0G #O   
 Or . N   
ENeUEE3   
NDzOZMD   
ON YIANW  
NAA LSA3
```

**90º Counterclockwise, Reversed**

```
X.SGA D   
 tENEENO  
 f0IRRUD  
 erH,EO   
 leTEHR   
 EzOZWAO  
hN NA.ET  
 O# G0N   
 N . rO   
 3EEUeNE  
 DMZOzDN  
WNAIY NO  
3ASL AAN
```

Comment: maybe spiral in or out?

Comment: That's a possibility